# When Varnas are already defined from were did yavana, mleccha or Chandalas originated

Tags: caste-system, varna

When Varnas are already defined as per Vedic principles from were did yavana, mleccha or Chandalas originated

Comment: yes 4 varnas are defined in Vedas. Those others fall outside the 4 varnas i.e. they don't believe or live by Vedas. Even if Hindus don't follow varnashram dharma, they're considered Mlecchas only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mlecchas appeared from the mixing of the original four Varnas (**Mahabharata 12.298.6-7**), the cause of which was the debauchery of women (**Bhagavad-gita 1.41-43, 3.24**). In the bodies of the mlecchas, they are born for the evil deeds of past lives (**Chhandogya Upanishad 5.10.7, Kaushitaki Upanishad 1.2; Manu Smriti 12.52-81**). A non-twice-born (Shudra or Mleccha) cannot become Brahman, Kshatriya or Vaishya just by wanting it (**Krishna Yajur Veda Taittiriya Samhita 7.1.1.6**). Dvijati must be born, for example, for the merits of their past lives (**Maitri Upanishad 3.2; Bhagavad Gita 14.18, Mahabharata 12.293.4-5, 12.304.45-48, 12.316.7-8, 12.320.92, 14.39.10; Manu-smriti 12.40-50**).
However, Sanatana-dharma is open to the Mlecchas (**Yajur Veda 26.2; Mahabharata 12.329.44, 12.330.4-6, 12.342.116-122; Manu-smriti 2.20**). The mlecchas can follow the Dharma and achieve Moksha (**Bhagavad-gita 9.29-32; Mahabharata 12.240.34, 14.19.62; Bhagavata Purana 5.1.35**).
There is also material evidence of proselytism in Hinduism already in antiquity, for example, the famous **Garuda Stambha Heliodor**, found in Besnagar, which depicts the following: *This column of Garuda was erected for the God of the gods Vasudeva, the bhagavata Heliodor, the son of Dion and a native of Taxila, who arrived as an ambassador from the great Greek king Antialkides to the savior-king Kasiputra Bhagabhadra.*

Comment: Quote exact verses too

Comment: Whose commentary on Mahabharat these citations are taken from? Only Ved Vyas Mahabharat is original. Pl give the details. Also the BG and Purana you are citing pl!

Comment: While I disagree with the guna/karma theory of varna, this answer is misleading and bad. By the force of austerities or by preforming ones duties one cna unnaturally quickly or slowly, but naturally become another varna or the inverse is true to degrade downwards. The verses quoted here are out of context.